# get object at end of method chain in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

### **EDITED**

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calculator
  attr_accessible :favorite_num
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calculator
  # does not have a favorite_num
end

class Calculator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kid
  belongs_to :teacher

  def compute(number)
    # takes the number passed in and multiplies it by
    # the favorite_num if it exists, otherwise returns 42
  end
end
```

What I need to be able to do is define `compute` above so that calls like the following work.

```
kid = Kid.first
=> #<User id: 1, favorite_num: 4, . . . >
kid.calculator.compute(5)
=> 20
teacher = Teacher.first
=> #<Teacher id: 1, . . . >
teacher.calculator.compute(5)
=> 42
```

Some additional constraints:

- I don't want to put a `compute` method in both the `Kid` and `Teacher` classes. This is because:

  - I want to keep things as dry as possible, and objects of several other classes have `Calculators` associated with them as well
  - doing so would require massive refactoring of the legacy code I'm working with (there are many `calculator.compute` calls scattered around the code, often invoked in less-than obvious ways)

**ORIGINAL VERSION**

If I have

```
object.foo
```

then the value of `self` in the context of `foo` is `object`. But what if I have:

```
object.foo.bar
```

How can I refer to `object` from within the definition of `bar`? `self` obviously won't work, since it just equals the return value of `object.foo`.

I cannot change the implementation of `foo`. And `foo` and `bar` cannot be called on objects of the same class.

Comment: *"`self` obviously won't work, since it just equals the return value of `object.foo`"*. Unless `object.foo` returns `self` e.g. `def foo; #some logic here; self; end;` in which case the return value from `#foo` is `object`. Or `object.foo` returns an object of the same class. take this for example `"String".gsub('St','B').downcase #=> 'bring'` becuase gsub returns a string and downcase is a string method so while it is not acting on the same string but a copy it is still in the context of the object `String`. If this does not help I would suggest making your question a bit more specific.

Comment: @engineersmnky: thanks! Unfortunately I can't change the implementation of `foo`. Just updated the question. And no, `object.foo` does not return an object in the same class as `object`. I'll clarify that too. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: This  seems like a broken design. binding_of_caller may help

Comment: @FrederickCheung Thanks! That may help indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The type of method chaining you are describing requires that the method `foo` return `self`. In order to achieve this, you must either change the method definition or monkey patch it. Changing the method definition is easy, just write `self` as the last statement of the method. Of course that means that you cannot return anything else from the method, so it's not a viable pattern for every method. I'd strongly advise against monkey patching, because I think the ugly code that results from that is not worth it.

Yet, there are some ways around this problem which do not require modifying the original method. The simplest solution is to write the method calls below each other. It may not be as "sexy", but it gets the job done.

```
object.foo
object.bar
```

If you would like to omit repeating `object`, you can use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap).

```
object.tap{|o| o.foo }.bar
```

Using [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) you can shorten this a bit.

```
object.tap(&:foo).bar
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, `foo` and `bar` cannot be called on the same object. `foo` returns an object of a different class than `object`.

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer is about. Have you actually tried any of the approaches? You should play around with `tap`, I think it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. Sorry if I'm not being clear. I have tried the approaches and really appreciate them. `object.tap(&:foo).bar` seems to call `foo` on `object` and then `bar` on `object` as well. That's not what I'm hoping to do. Could you maybe give me an example of how you would reference object from within the definition of `bar`?

Comment: Well when you have a method `bar`, you can just pass `object` as an argument and then call `bar(object.tap(&:foo))`, or `object.foo` and in the next line `bar(object)`. Or just pass `object` to `bar` and call `foo` inside the `bar` method.

Comment: Great, that's helpful. Still not quite what I need--but I don't think that's your fault! I think I need to flesh out my description of the problem a bit better. I'll try to do so above.